# Http request 500 internal server error on Axios put

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have an issue submitting my updated data to database.
It accepts all input but when I'm trying to get it saved it gets the error.

This is my route:

```
Route::resource('Sales', 'SalesController');
```

How I put my data:

```
axios.put('/Sales/' + id)
```

My update method:

```
public function update(Request $req, $id){
$sales = Sales::find($id);
$sales = new Sales;
$sales->itemQty = $req['itemQty'];
$sales->itemID = $req['itemID'];
$sales->save();
}
```

My Editing form:

```
<div class="card-body"  v-for="(sale, index) in sales" :key="sale.id">
              <form action="/Sales" method="post">
                  <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
                      <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="form-inline">
                          <div class="mr-3 mt-2">Item ID: </div>
                          <input class="form-control mt-2 col" name="itemID[]" maxlength="12" v-model="sale.itemID">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-inline">
                          <div class="mr-2 mt-2">Quantity: </div>
                          <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control mt-2 col" placeholder="Quantity" name="itemQty[]" v-model="sale.itemQty">
                        </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="updatesale" style="margin:0 auto; text-align: center;">
                    <button class="btn btn-success mt-2" type="button" name="button" v-on:click="updateSalesRec(sale.id)">Update</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please show the exact error

Comment: How do I get the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another instance of the `Sales` object after finding it:

```
public function update(Request $req, $id){
    $sales = Sales::find($id);
    $sales->itemQty = $req['itemQty'];
    $sales->itemID = $req['itemID'];
    $sales->save();
}
```

I don't think your intention is to have your data submitted in array. So remove `[]` from the input field names:

```
<div class="card-body"  v-for="(sale, index) in sales" :key="sale.id">
          <form action="/Sales" method="post">
              <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
                  <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="form-inline">
                      <div class="mr-3 mt-2">Item ID: </div>
                      <input class="form-control mt-2 col" name="itemID" maxlength="12" v-model="sale.itemID">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-inline">
                      <div class="mr-2 mt-2">Quantity: </div>
                      <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control mt-2 col" placeholder="Quantity" name="itemQty" v-model="sale.itemQty">
                    </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="updatesale" style="margin:0 auto; text-align: center;">
                <button class="btn btn-success mt-2" type="button" name="button" v-on:click="updateSalesRec(sale.id)">Update</button>
              </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Did not make any differences. However I did notice something with my delete function. 
public function destroy(Request $req, $id) {
    $sales = Sales::find($id);
    $sales->delete();
    return redirect()->action('pagesController@dSales');
  }

This works although I do get 500 internal sever error

Comment: Found the error. Apparently Im sending null data even with the new input so i get Integrity Violation Error. What do I do with this>

Comment: Which field is submitting the null data? You can set the value before it is submitted, or set a default value on database. If you have some constrains on the database field (like unique), then you either remove the constraint or ensure it is always satisfied.

Comment: All fields. The default value of database is fine as I can do initial post request to have my data submitted. This however, my edited data does not get accepted and is submitted as null. How do I make sure upon clearing the existing data from the field, then the newly input data is being set ?